# Create a list of directories

Tags: scripting, tcsh

I have a list of names in a text file (`list.txt`) I want to create a list of folders for the names included in that file. I wrote the following script, but it doesn't work and I don't know what is wrong:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
for name_id in `cat <path to list.txt>/list.txt` ; do
mkdir <name_id>${name_id}
```

The file `list.txt` and the scripts are in the same folder.

Comment: I don't know tsch, but if it's anything like bash, you probably need to terminate the `do` block with `done`? Also, you use `name_id` to start, then refer to `subj_id`.

Comment: `for` is `bash`, not `tcsh`.

Comment: The equivalent in `tcsh` is `foreach`, but it doesn't have a `do` clause. Also, you misspelled `tcsh`.

Comment: But it would be best not to use `tcsh` for scripting, use a POSIX-style shell. See http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: Are you required to use tcsh or can you use any shell?

Comment: If you're truly looking to use tcsh here's the syntax for the foreach: http://www.tcsh.org/ForLoop

Comment: @Thanks slm for your help. Yes I need to use tcsh. is the code like this correct foreach x <path>/(list.txt)
    mkdir <path>/$x
  end

Comment: See my answer..

Comment: @MJA if you need to use `tcsh` why do you accept an answer that doesn't use it at all, apart from  redirection that can be done in any other shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
xargs mkdir <list.txt
```

This works because if you give multiple arguments to `mkdir` it will happily create all the directories it can create. `xargs` simply "flattens" your text file by replacing newlines with spaces, thereby invoking `mkdir` with a long list of arguments containing all your directory names at once instead of one at a time.

If you want to add a fixed prefix (or suffix, or both):

```
xargs -I, mkdir prefix_, <list.txt
```

Whatever you put after the `-I` switch (a comma in this case) is replaced by the name that is read from the file.

One more thing, I would add quotes just in case the file names in your text file have spaces in them or other "special" characters:

```
xargs -I, mkdir "," <list.txt
```

or

```
xargs -I, mkdir "prefix_," <list.txt
```

Comment: It fails if list.txt contains ".

Answer (score 1):

In your example, your confusing shell scripting commands. You have to pay special attention to which scripting language you're using and then adhere to its commands' syntax. In your example you're using turbo C shell (tcsh) however you're then mixing in Bash/Bourne shell commands and syntaxes.

You can use the following approach if you truly want `tcsh`. Say I had this sample file:

```
$ cat afile 
1
2
3
4
5
```

And this script:

```
$ cat cmd.csh 
#!/bin/tcsh

foreach i (`cat afile`) 
  echo "$i" 
end
```

Running it will produce this output:

```
$ ./cmd.csh
1
2
3
4
5
```

So to complete the task, we can add in the `mkdir` command after the `echo`:

```
$ cat cmd1.csh 
#!/bin/tcsh

foreach i (`cat afile`) 
  echo "making directory: $i" 
  mkdir "$i"
end
```

Now when we run it:

```
$ ./cmd1.csh 
making directory: 1
making directory: 2
making directory: 3
making directory: 4
making directory: 5
```

Resulting in the directories getting created:

```
$ ls -l
total 32
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Oct 16 18:58 1
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Oct 16 18:58 2
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Oct 16 18:58 3
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Oct 16 18:58 4
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml 4096 Oct 16 18:58 5
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml   11 Oct 16 18:47 afile
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 saml saml   86 Oct 16 18:56 cmd1.csh
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 saml saml   55 Oct 16 18:51 cmd.csh
```

Comment: Why echo I need mkdir ?

Comment: @MJA - For demo purposes.

Comment: @MJA - see updates

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel -q mkdir '<name_id>'{} < list.txt
```

Opposite xargs it deals correctly with special characters - such as <, >, ', " and space.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. You can do:

```
mkdir `sed 's/^/<name_id>/' <path to list.txt>/list.txt`
```

Comment: @Barmer. Thanks but I got the following message "name_id: No such file or directory"

Comment: He's using a tcsh not a Bourne shell.

Comment: @MJA I assumed `<name_id>` was just a placeholder in your original question, and I just copied it here. You have to replace it with the actual prefix that you want to put at the front of every directory name in `list.txt`.

Comment: @slm I think my command should work in both tcsh and Bourne shell.

Comment: @Barmar - you're correct, I just tried it.