# How can a script run many processes at the same time?

Tags: scripting

I want my code to run many processes at the same time.
The **following example** for a code and the source is **StackExchange (Unix&Linux )** web site.

```
> #!/bin/bash
> for i in $(cat lis.txt); do
>      echo "$i"
>      wait
>      mkdir "$i"
>  done
```

This simple code is designed to create a list of directories from a list of names included in text file. When we run the code, it is creating the folders one by one. How can I modify this code to create all the folders at the same time i.e to do all the job at the same time?

Comment: Seriously? We have an answer suggesting `for i in $(cat file)`? Where? Please let me know and I'll fix it.

Comment: In this previous code. it is creating the folders one by one not all of them together at the same time. If I am wrong please correct my understanding for this code.

Comment: @terdon This site does have an answer that does that - it was written by the OP. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162640/49439

Comment: @MJA I think this answer to your previous question http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162653/49439 - use xargs - will also answer this question.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks, I fixed it :). MJA, I suggest you also use the `while read i; do ...; < list.txt` approach. To make them run at once, just add `&` to the end of the mkdir command: `mkdir $i &`

Comment: @ trendon. Thanks. Actually I gave this code as an example for my original question. How can the code run one command like (mkdir in my example) to create folders for all the names in the file included in this code?

Comment: @ Thanks. I am learning a lot from you guys.

Comment: @terdon `for i in $(cat file)` can be ok, if you know that the content of the file is whitespace-separated words with no special characters. This is not good if the lines in `file` can be e.g. unconstrainted file names.

Comment: @Gilles exactly, which is why I consider it a very bad idea to post that loop as an answer since we usually don't know what the OP will have in `file`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have GNU Parallel you can do any of these:

```
parallel mkdir :::: list.txt
parallel -a list.txt mkdir
cat list.txt | parallel mkdir
```

All new computers have multiple cores, but most programs are serial in nature and will therefore not use the multiple cores. However, many tasks are extremely parallelizeable:

- Run the same program on many files
- Run the same program for every line in a file
- Run the same program for every block in a file

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Answer (score 3):

This script will create a directory for each of the lines in `list.txt`. It can deal with spaces but not other weird characters (such as `\r or`\t` and the like, but that shouldn't be an issue here):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while IFS= read -r dir
do
  mkdir -- "$dir" &
done < list.txt
```

The `&` sends the job to the background so the script will continue immediately and not wait for the `mkdir` to finish. This is almost certainly undetectable with `mkdir` but can be important for other operations.

For future reference, if you need to be able to deal with arbitrary characters, use `read -r` instead. Also, for more complex parallelization tasks, look into [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).